# Truly unbuffered file uploads in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, file-upload

The [ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#upload-large-files-with-streaming) on file uploading talks about the option to upload files in an unbuffered way using `MultipartReader`, however as I understand it, this only reads each `MultipartSection` in an unbuffered way - it has to read a whole `MultipartSection` before your code gets called with the whole section being buffered in memory (I have confirmed this by logging, and my logging only gets called once the HTTP request has finished posting).  If you're uploading a large file as one `MultipartSection` this isn't terribly helpful.

Is there a way to do truly unbuffered uploading in ASP.NET Core (or at least, have the buffer be something small like 32kb)?  As the data comes in from the client, it would be made available to my code to stream out to disk or uploaded somewhere else over a fast network connection?

Comment: What do you think about wrapping `Request.Body` with `StreamReader`, specifying `bufferSize` in constructor? Sounds like you can read into files that way and buffer size is controlled.

Comment: You are dealing with a Net (Windows) Stream which is getting filled with the upload data.  It doesn't have a method to reuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it has to read a whole MultipartSection before your code gets called with the whole section being buffered in memory (I have confirmed this by logging, and my logging only gets called once the HTTP request has finished posting). If you're uploading a large file as one MultipartSection this isn't terribly helpful.

The code gets called once after HTTP request has finished posting. This is expected, but it doesn't means Asp.net core will buffer the data.

As the document mentioned that there are two general approaches for uploading files buffering and streaming in ASP.Net core. For the buffering approach, the entire file is read into an **IFormFile**. And for the streaming, there is no additional object created by the Asp.net core, it read the content directly from **HttpContext.Request.Body**, instead of created the IFormFile by Asp.NET Core.

And the goal of streaming approach is reducing the demands for memory or disk space when uploading files as it states below:

***The file is received from a multipart request and directly processed or saved by the app. Streaming doesn't improve performance significantly. Streaming reduces the demands for memory or disk space when uploading files.***

Comment: If the machine waits until the entire POST before processing the request, it MUST buffer all of the data somewhere in memory or it won't have access to the POST data.  Whether asp.net core itself is doing that or some other aspect of the stack, that data is being buffered somewhere because it hasn't been processed yet.  So I don't really understand how this approach reduces memory requirements.

Comment: Yes, this is due to the [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview), it based on message (as opposed to a stream of data).   When the server receive the request, it already be cached, and then it passed to the web framework(Asp.NET Core). When we mean reducing memory it compared to upload files using buffering which created IFromFile(**Buffer in Asp.NET Core**).

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT, I Buffering in Asp.Net core done in ModelBinding or somewhere else? I am thinking about using Request.Form.Files to get Stream files without using ModelBinding. But again it is IFormFiles, Is It also buffered?